# NGINX reverse proxy to https upstream

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

trying to set up Nginx reverse proxy in front of AWS Elastic Load Balancer with TSL enabled on it.

The configuration I've tried:

```
events {}
http {
   upstream pricing {
       server pricing-api.my-awselb.com:443;
   }

   server {
       listen       80;
       server_name  localhost;

       location /pricing {
         proxy_pass https://pricing;
       }
   }
}
```

Now when I run Nginx in docker locally on port 8080 when I try test it I get 404

```
> http http://localhost:8080/pricing
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 21 Oct 2020 21:47:56 GMT
Server: nginx/1.19.3
```

upstream itself is accessible from my local machine:

```
> http https://pricing-api.my-awselb.com
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 21 Oct 2020 21:54:36 GMT
Location: /swagger
Server: Kestrel
```

Whats wrong with my Nginx configuration?

Comment: Your probably missing a correct Host header. The problem with using an `upstream` block is that it masks the true name of the service you are attempting to access. You need to use `proxy_pass https://pricing-api.my-awselb.com;` or `proxy_set_header Host pricing-api.my-awselb.com;`

Comment: @RichardSmith `proxy_pass https://pricing-api.my-awselb.com` also gives me 404...

Comment: Ah, I see It appends for some reason /pricing as a segment to the origin domain, i.e. 

`GET localhost/pricing goes to https://pricing-api.my-awselb.com/pricing`

Don't understand why...

Comment: If you want to strip off `/pricing`, use `proxy_pass https://pricing-api.my-awselb.com/;`